# Hide SharepointSearchBackEnd from result block

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-search, query-rule, promoted-results

I have created a promoted results result block to display a few users in the search results web part. However this result block displays as "SharePointSearchBackEnd:People Results for {searchTerm}". Can't I hide the **SharepointSearchBackEnd** keyword?

My query rule is at the sub-site level.

Comment: In the result block settings what is your Result Block Title?

Comment: "People Results for {searchTerm}"

Comment: Strange, when you test the query rules on the test page with the search term what other query rules are firing? Could it be that you are not troubleshooting the right rule?

Comment: The query rule is firing correctly and the results are also returned as expected. Its just that I am getting an additional keyword before the "People Results for {searchTerm}" header. I have federated search enabled in my environment which federated the results from SharePoint Online to on-prem. But the people results are from on-prem index only.